# Identifying image clicks

Tags: javascript, html

i have the following code in which i have images and on them i have dislike. i want to identify on which image the dislike has been clicked? how do i do that?

```
<div class="product_title"><a href="details.html">Levi's Men's Cotton T-Shirt</a></div>
      <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><img src="images/T1.jpg" alt="" border="0" id="T1"/></a></div>
       <div class="product_img"><img src="images/dislike.jpeg" onclick="getId();" align="right" id="d1"/></a></div>
      <div class="prod_price"><span class="reduce">350$</span> <span class="price">270$</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="prod_details_tab"> <a href="#" title="header=[Add to cart] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/cart.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Specials] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favs.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Gifts] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favorites.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="details.html" class="prod_details">details</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prod_box">
    <div class="top_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="center_prod_box">
      <div class="product_title"><a href="details.html">UB Stylish T-shirt</a></div>
      <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><img src="images/T2.jpg" alt="" border="0" id="T2"/></a></div>
       <div class="product_img"><img src="images/dislike.jpeg" alt="" border="0" align="right" id="d2"/></a></div>
      <div class="prod_price"><span class="price">270$</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="prod_details_tab"> <a href="#" title="header=[Add to cart] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/cart.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Specials] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favs.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Gifts] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favorites.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="details.html" class="prod_details">details</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prod_box">
    <div class="top_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="center_prod_box">
      <div class="product_title"><a href="details.html">Jacob n John T-Shirt</a></div>
      <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><img src="images/T3.jpg" alt="" border="0" id="T3" /></a></div>
       <div class="product_img"><img src="images/dislike.jpeg" alt="" border="0" align="right" id="d3"/></a></div>
      <div class="prod_price"><span class="reduce">350$</span> <span class="price">270$</span></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `$(this).closest('.center_prod_box').find('a img')`

Comment: You have invalid markup...

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the dislike image button with onclick event. Find the id of the element and then use the id to find the product id.

As your markup is structured, id of element is d`i` then corresponding id of product is t`i`.